# How to filter an array of objects using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Background**

I've been teaching myself AngularJS this past week. I created a basic application that gets Twitch data for each Twitch channel and creates an array of "channel" objects that holds the following properties; name, logo url, streaming (yes or no), and channel url. So far I've used Angular to print each channel object by its properties to a table using the ng-repeat directive (love that feature).

**Problem/ Question**

I want to be able to sort the list of objects in the table whenever a user clicks the online and offline buttons thus filtering the channels by its "streaming" property. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to filter the channels by its property. Can anyone help?

HTML

```
  <div ng-controller="MainController" >
  <div class="container" id="test">
    <div class="row">
        <header>
            <ul id="mainMenu">
                <li class="activeMenu" ng-click="filterGo('streaming')">All</li>
                <li ng-click="filterGo('streaming')">Online</li>
                <li ng-click="filterGo('streaming')">Offline</li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <div class="center-block" >
        <table class="table table-hover" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Logo</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Channel</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Online</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="channel in twitchChannels | filter:filtered"   ng-click="setSelected();">
                    <td ><img id="size" ng-src="{{ channel.logo }}"></td>
                    <td >{{ channel.user }}</td>
                    <td >{{ channel.streaming }}</td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
var arr = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var channels = [];
var count = 0;
var online = "";

// channel object 
function Channel(user, name, logo, streaming) {
    this.user = user;
    this.name = name;
    this.logo = logo;
    this.streaming = streaming;
    this.url = "https://www.twitch.tv/" + this.name;
}

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http, $window) { 
    // loops through array of channels 
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        (function(i) { 

            $http.get("https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/" + arr[i]).success(function(data) {

                var channel = data.display_name;
                var name = data.name;
                var logo = data.logo;

                $http.get("https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/" + arr[i]).success(function(json) {
                    var streaming = (json.stream === null) ? false : true;
                    if(streaming) {
                        online = "YES";
                        channels[count] = new Channel(channel, name, logo, online);
                    } else {
                        online = "NO";
                        channels[count] = new Channel(channel, name, logo, online);
                    }
                    count++;
                });
            });
         })(i);
    }

    $scope.twitchChannels = channels;

    // if channel row is clicked take user to url 
    $scope.setSelected = function() {
        $scope.selected = this.channel.url;
        $window.open($scope.selected);
    };

     // Need help here! 
     $scope.filterGo = function(x) {    
        $scope.filtered = x;
    }

});
```

Here is the a link for reference:http://codepen.io/bryanpleblanc/pen/jBBmgN

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can put your *HTML/CSS/JS*  code and make it executable snippet. You can also add external resources and babel as parser(*if need be*)

Comment: Great suggestion! I'll do that next time!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `filterGo` function to this

```
$scope.filterGo = function(x) {
        $scope.filtered = channels.filter(c => c.streaming === x);
}
```

and your `ng-click` to

```
<li ng-click="filterGo('YES')">Online</li>
<li ng-click="filterGo('NO')">Offline</li>
```

**Note**

You'd better use a boolean instead of `YES` and `NO`. This will be easier.

Like this

```
$http.get("https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/" + arr[i]).success(function(json) {
    channels[count] = new Channel(channel, name, logo, json.stream !== null);
    count++;
});
```

Your buttons

```
<li ng-click="filterGo(true)">Online</li>
<li ng-click="filterGo(false)">Offline</li>
```

And the filter

```
$scope.filterGo = function(x) {
        $scope.filtered = channels.filter(c => c.streaming);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your suggestion makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the objects array by one of the properties of those objects you'll need to use an object as a filter.

This should work:

```
<li class="activeMenu" ng-click="filterGo({streaming : undefined})">All</li>
<li ng-click="filterGo({streaming : 'YES'})">Online</li>
<li ng-click="filterGo({streaming : 'NO'})">Offline</li>
```

As it is now, your code is filtering the array elements that are equal to the sting `streaming` which is none of them because the array contains objects.

Comment: Thank you Titus. Well explained!